# Can I point specific prefixed wildcard sub-domain to another set of name servers for the same DNS domain but hosted elsewhere?

Tags: subdomain, nameserver, dns-zone, ns-record

I have a domain, say, `example.com` hosted in GoDaddy. I want to create all DNS records starting with `dev` for this domain in route53 of our Dev AWS account (e.g. `dev-abc.example.com`, `dev-xyz.example.com`).

I was able to make them working the following ways:

**On my AWS account:**

1. I created a hosted zone of the same `example.com` domain in route53.
2. Zone `example.com` in route53 now got NS records `ns-111.awsdns-11.net.` and `ns-111.awsdns-11.com.`.

**On GoDaddy:**

Under `example.com` zone, I created the following NS records to point `dev-abc.example.com` and `dev-xyz.example.com` to route53 of my AWS account:

```
ns  dev-abc     ns-111.awsdns-11.net    600 seconds
ns  dev-abc     ns-111.awsdns-11.com    600 seconds
ns  dev-xyz     ns-111.awsdns-11.net    600 seconds
ns  dev-xyz     ns-111.awsdns-11.com    600 seconds
```

Now, in route53 of my AWS account, I can create these two records (`dev-abc.example.com` and `dev-xyz.example.com`) of any valid type, and they work.

What I wanted to do is to create `dev` prefixed wildcard NS records under `example.com` zone in GoDaddy like below to point any records starts with `dev` to route53 of my AWS account.

```
ns  dev*    ns-111.awsdns-11.net    600 seconds
ns  dev*    ns-111.awsdns-11.com    600 seconds
```

This way I won't have to create NS records in GoDaddy for each `dev` prefixed record I want to create in route53 of my AWS account.

Is there a way to do this so I do not have to create the NS records in GoDaddy for each of the records I want to create under `example.com` zone in route53 of my AWS account?

Please note that, I understand that I can create a sub-domain `dev.example.com` zone in route53 of my AWS account, and then I can create records like `app1.dev.example.com`, `app2.dev.example.com` and so on there, but I do not want to do that.

Comment: What is the reason behing your `dev-abc` naming requirement? Is there some reason why the `example.com` NS records cannot point to Route53?

Comment: I have 3 AWS accounts, one for each of the environments, Dev, UAT and Prod. Managing each of these zones for their own environments helps managing their own DNS records using CloudFormation templates easily. Otherwise, I need to use Custom Resources in CloudFormation templates to manage the DNS records in cross-accounts, which I’m trying to avoid.

Comment: Why does it have to be `dev-abc` and not `abc.dev` with a subdomain?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - Pointing `dev.example.com` to the new set of name servers and then create records there like `abc.dev.example.com` or `xyz.dev.example.com` is simple. Here we are avoiding sub-sub-domain.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see the reason why you need to avoid sub-sub-domain?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, thanks for your efforts trying to help me. Do you have the answer to what I am looking for?

Comment: The answer has already been given below. Your requirement of `dev-abc` cannot be implemented. You need to use the subdomain approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delegate `dev-*.example.com`, but you could delegate `*.dev.example.com` with `dev.example.com NS`. I suggest changing the naming pattern to match your requirements.